# How to close AJP port that's open to the world?

Tags: centos, port

I inherited a bunch of physical and virtual servers. This morning I ran nmap against all of the systems to look for vulnerabilities. An odd thing that I noticed is that on one, and only one, of my machines port 8009 (the tomcat AJP port) is open to the world. I verified this by telneting to the machine on that port. On other machines the telnet connection is refused.

I didn't set up this environment and I'm not a sysadmin guru so I'm wondering how I can figure out what file/command/setting is responsible for this. Puppet manages the software and configuration on all of the machines and I don't see any firewall exceptions for that machine.

The machine in question runs CentOS 5.11.

UPDATE:

iptables shows this:

```
[root@server conf]# /sbin/iptables -L | grep 8009
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:8009
```

So, I guess I can just disable that access.

Answer (score 1):

you can tell which process has opened a port with (as root):

`netstat -ntlup | grep 8009`

this will display all the PID of the process, which you can find in `ps -ef | grep pid`.

Most *nix servers control interface and port bindings with their main config file. Here is a thread about how to configure tomcat interface and port bindings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o